# Cyrillic product name for ios app in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode6, cyrillic

When I create an application with cyrillic product name my bundle identifier has strange name!? My app will have only one cyrillic language without localization.

[screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9tr9fXb0r7LUHQyQld6TjZfOFk/view?usp=sharing)

Is this a problem for publishing in app store?

Comment: You might have to latinize the bundle identifier. It won't show to end-users.

Comment: I can't edit the bundle identifier. I trying to delete this .aggressione.--------, but i can't.

Comment: That seems wrong. You should always be able to edit your bundle identifier on that screen. Try editing it directly in the info.plist attached to your project.

Comment: This is my info.plist before editting [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9tr9fXb0r7LZjB3ZmMxRGE3T3M&authuser=0) and this is after editing [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9tr9fXb0r7LcG12eDVVQzhoUmc&authuser=0). Now my bundle identifier is changed [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9tr9fXb0r7LcXc2dTBkS2ZJMVk&authuser=0) It's ok?

Comment: That will probably be acceptable.